# Arduino How can i store the last IR code to check if it needs repeating?

Tags: c++, arduino, embedded

I'm just learning Arduino and i've got a DC Motor & IR Receiver connected. It's working fine if i press the button once but i can't figure out how to keep the motor spinning if i hold the button down as the REPEAT command is the same numbers.

I figured i would store the last code sent and check if the repeat command and last code match but it doesn't seem to be working and can't figure out why.

```
#include <IRremote.h>

int IRpin = 11;  // pin for the IR sensor
IRrecv irrecv(IRpin);
decode_results results;
int lastCode;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Enable IR Receiver.
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:


if

 (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
  Serial.println(results.value);
  irrecv.resume(); 
  Serial.println("Last Code is set to: ");
  Serial.write(lastCode);


  if(results.value== 16748655 || (results.value== 4294967295 && lastCode== 16748655)) // Your ON button value                                       
  {
      digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(7, LOW);
      analogWrite(9, 255);
      delay(1000);
      analogWrite(9, 0);
      lastCode= 16748655;

  }


  else if(results.value == 16769055 || (results.value== 4294967295 && lastCode== 16769055)) // Your OFF button value 
  {
      digitalWrite(8, LOW);
      digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
      analogWrite(9, 255);
      delay(1000);
      analogWrite(9, 0);
      lastCode= 16769055;

  }
}


}
```

Comment: You should avoid 32 bit arithmetic. It's an antique 8-bit MCU, not a PC.

Comment: Thx for your comment, but what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Offopic: read about "Magic Numbers"

Comment: When you let an 8 bit AVR handle 32 bit numbers, it will have to inline big chunks of software libraries in the machine code, making the program dreadfully slow. In some cases there's no way around it, but here there's just no way that your sensors have 32 bit accuracy, so you are just letting the CPU chew empty air for no reason. The root of the problem is the hobbyist who write "irremote.h", judging by github it looks like a rookie PC programmer. And they also have an interrupt firing every 50us. I'd be surprised if the AVR can even process the ISR code itself in 50us... disassemble!

Comment: @Lundin: However, the `results.value` _is_ a 32 bit int, and the c++ Compiler will handle that number size optimally. Normally, it's easier human readable when written in hex format, but that's a different topic.

Comment: `int lastcode;` is wrong. results.value is a 32 bit value, which does not fit into an Arduino int. Use `uint32_t lastcode; ` and store it using `lastcode = results.value; ` However, not all IRControls repeat the same code when pressed longer.

Comment: Stick to using one of the analog input pins for an IR input.

Comment: @Lundin - it is not about 32 bit sensor accuracy - these are IR Remote control codes.  They appear to be 24 bit, but the actual width for the specific encoding is provided in [`decoded_result`](https://bengtmartensson.github.io/Arduino-IRremote/classdecode__results.html).  No arithmetic is performed on them.  The encoding is determined by the IR remote - he has no choice in the matter.  I have not looked at the IRremote code to assess its efficiency otherwise, you may have a point, but clearly misunderstand the purpose of the code so I'd reserve judgement.

Answer (score 1):

A more reliable approach to running the motor until the button is released is to use a "no-code" timeout.  That is, if the "no code" state persists for a period longer than the auto-repeat period, then it has been released.

It is not clear in your code what the 1 second analogue pulse is for, but placing long delays in your `loop()` function makes your system far less responsive.  Better to poll the system tick and "do stuff" when it is time to do so.  Also magic numbers should be avoided if you want anyone to understand your code and avoid errors in maintenance.

The following uses system tick polling to implement the "no-code" timeout.  I have omitted the motor on/off code because it is not clear what you are doing there with the 1 second delays.

```
#define NO_CODE        0xFFFFFFFFul
#define MOTOR_ON_CODE  0xFF906Ful
#define MOTOR_OFF_CODE 0xFFE01Ful
#define STOP_TIME_MS   250ul  // stop after button release for 250ms

void loop( )
{
    static unsigned long last_on_time = 0 ; 

    if( irrecv.decode( &results ) )
    {
        irrecv.resume() ;

        unsigned long code = results.value ;

        // If motor off code or no code timeout...
        if( code == MOTOR_OFF_CODE ||
            (code == NO_CODE && millis() - last_on_time > STOP_TIME_MS) )
        {
            // Motor off
            ...
        }
        else if( code == MOTOR_ON_CODE )
        {
            // Continuously update last on time while button is held
            last_on_time = millis() ;

            // Motor on
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I have included response to the motor-off code, but that may not be necessary, since the motor will be switched off 250ms (or whatever time you choose) after the ON button is released in any case.  You might instead have a forward/reverse button and release either to stop:

```
#define NO_CODE        0xFFFFFFFFul
#define MOTOR_FWD_CODE 0xFF906Ful
#define MOTOR_REV_CODE 0xFFE01Ful
#define STOP_TIME_MS   250ul  // stop after button release for 250ms

void loop( )
{
    static unsigned long last_on_time = 0 ; 

    if( irrecv.decode( &results ) )
    {
        irrecv.resume() ;

        unsigned long code = results.value ;
        switch( code )
        {
            case NO_CODE :
            {
                if( millis() - last_on_time > STOP_TIME_MS )
                {
                    // Motor off
                    ...          
                }
            }
            break ;

            case MOTOR_FWD_CODE :
            {
                // Continuously update last on time while button is held
                last_on_time = millis() ;

                // Motor forward
                ...
            }
            break ;

            case MOTOR_FWD_CODE :
            {
                // Continuously update last on time while button is held
                last_on_time = millis() ;

                // Motor reverse
                ...
            }
            break ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `static unsigned long last_on_time = millis() ;` Surely this is a bug? Since it will be executed during `.data`/default ctor initialization long before hitting this code. You may as well initialize it to `STOP_TIME_MS+1; // motor off`.

Comment: Also, we shouldn't mix hex literals of different types. `NO_CODE` is of type `unsigned long`, but `MOTOR_FWD_CODE` etc are of type `long`. So there's conflicting types used in the `switch` - in this case nothing will happen because `code` is unsigned long, so you get a conversion to that. But if it was `int` etc, subtle bugs could happen here. Always suffix hex constants with the intended type, in this case `ul`.

Comment: @Lundin potentially.  In practice the static is initialised on first call to the function, but that may be undefined.

Comment: No, `static` variables are never initialized when a function is called, but during program start-up.

Comment: @Lundin all good points. I am of course not able to build or test this code, it should be regarded as a design pattern, not perhaps complete or even correct.  Feel free to fix these issues.  I'm on a phone at the moment, and code editing is not straight forward.  Thanks.

Comment: @Lundin I have tested similar code stepping in a debugger, and I know that to be untrue. YMMV.

Comment: The debugger might not show the variables before you enter scope, but that's another story. The C and C++ standards actually _require_ that the variable isn't initialized there. For example C11 5.1.2 "All objects with static storage duration shall be initialized (set to their
initial values) before program startup. The manner and timing of such _initialization_ are otherwise unspecified." This means that the CRT must initialize them before main() is called, period. And all systems I have ever seen, embedded or not, does just that.

Comment: @Lundin The bug is in this case benign. The worse that will happen is the motor which is already off will be switched off. The variable is assigned whenever the motor is switched on.  However I agree the issue should not stand if there is any potential to start machinery inappropriately.

Comment: @Lundin yes but that allows (and only requires) the static to only be initialised to zero. In the debugger, I have explicitly stepped into the function used to initialise.

Comment: No, it applies to all manner of static initialization, otherwise the system would be non-conforming. Which is why the `static` variable isn't stored on the stack but in `.data` or `.bss`.

Comment: My last word on the subject:  Refer to http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf section 6.7, part 4.  It was defined.  I take the point that it was unnecessary..

Comment: The relevant part in that document is 3.6.2 "Together, zero-initialization and constant initialization are called _static initialization_; all other initialization is
dynamic initialization. Static initialization shall be performed before any dynamic initialization takes place." Meaning that a conforming C++ compiler must ensure that all static initialization is done before main() is called. And that's how compilers work in practice too: the C++ CRT is splitting static initialization in 3 parts: constant init in `.data`, zero-init in `.bss` and C++ ctors in a chew-away-all-performance loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193317/discussion-between-clifford-and-lundin).